Removing Z coordinate from GeoJSON using QGIS
Someone shared with me a GeojJSON file that includes Z coordinates. Not only this coordinate is useless (0 everywhere) but it's not respecting the expected scheme of the destination tool.
I know how to do it in Python but my team members are more used to QGIS.
How can I remove the Z coordinate from this GeojJSON using only the QGIS interface?
{ 
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "RSP-A Polygons-wgs84",
  "crs": { 
    "type": "name", 
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    } 
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature", 
      "properties": { 
        "ProductionPlace": "<internal code>", 
        "Area": 0.09, 
        "Country": "UG",
        "Farm ID": "<internal code>"  
      }, 
      "geometry": { 
        "type": "Polygon", 
        "coordinates": [
          [ 
            [ 30.3874368, -0.6509562, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.387418, -0.6509776, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3873939, -0.6510232, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3874019, -0.6510635, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3874046, -0.651093, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3874448, -0.6511251, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3874904, -0.6511251, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3875226, -0.6511546, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3875575, -0.6511573, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3875951, -0.65116, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3876514, -0.6511573, 0.0 ],
            [ 30.3876755, -0.6511091, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3876889, -0.6510742, 0.0 ],  
            [ 30.3877238, -0.651093, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3877479, -0.651093, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3877667, -0.6510688, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3877667, -0.6510232, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3877506, -0.6509642, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3877184, -0.6509159, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3876809, -0.650873, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3875816, -0.6508811, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3875495, -0.650932, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3875253, -0.650924, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3875012, -0.6509347, 0.0 ],
            [ 30.3874797, -0.6509267, 0.0 ], 
            [ 30.3874368, -0.6509562, 0.0 ] 
          ] 
        ] 
      } 
    }
  ]
}


You can use the "Drop M/Z values" processing algorithm:

Output GeoJSON:
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "output",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "xy_coordinate_resolution": 1e-15,
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "ProductionPlace": "<internal code>",
                "Area": 0.09,
                "Country": "UG",
                "Farm ID": "<internal code>"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            30.3874368,
                            -0.6509562
                        ],
                        [
                            30.387418,
                            -0.6509776
                        ],
                        [
                            30.3873939,
                            -0.6510232
                        ],
...}

